# How to make Quartz scheduler to execute jobs asynchronously(parallelly)?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I have 56 jobs scheduled as cronTrigger, all at an exact same time.

I expect these jobs all start executing together, without having any sequence.
like each one executing in it's own Thread. however quartz scheduler executes them one by one.

I did some research, and found this 
[Quartz Thread Execution Parallel or Sequential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361939/quartz-thread-execution-parallel-or-sequential) that suggest setting of following properties in quartz.properties file:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount = 60 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 60
```

sad to say, it didn't work for me. still when one of my jobs encounters an exception, it keeps trying to run the job, which is fine, but other jobs never execute until this one totally fails after some attemps.

Do you know how to make the scheduler to exhibit a parallel behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you want these to start at *exactly* the same time you're out of luck. That's physically impossible.

Comment: not that exact :) I mean let's say, my first job takes 30 seconds to complete, I want my second job to be started and working while the first one is executing. let's say one second after the first one.

Comment: oops, I found the problem, actually the code was overriding the properties file config by creating an instance of Properties class in the code. so I'm sorry for my nonsense question. ;)